# Can I use function(e) twice or more in the same file?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it okay to use the same function in the same file twice or more

```
    document.getElementById('one').onlick = function test(e) 
    {
        var key = e.which;
        if(key === 13)
        {
            document.getElementById('two').click();
            return true;  
        }
    }
```

The other one is

```
    document.getElementById('elem').onlick = function test(e)
    { 
        document.getElementById('divtext').innerHTML=''; 
        e.preventDefault();   
        x--;
    }
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Thanks, Just a newbie.

Comment: Being new isn't a reason to have skipped the above. Quite the opposite, it's a reason to have paid particular attention to those things when asking the question. (The edit still needs work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function (e) is an anonymous function, you can have as many as you like.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Keith, I have to keypress(function(e)) and only one works, they are in different forms but in the same file, they codes are the same only the fields and button names are different. one for update password form and one for adding user form. What could be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell from just the bits you have posted.  For example what is inputset, in jquery your targeting an id, so maybe you meant to do -> $('#lessfield').on("click", function (e)  instead.